# Local parse server sync to cloud parse server

Tags: mongodb, parse-server

How to sync the local parse server to the cloud parse server?
Is the local parse server objectId will not change once it sync to the cloud parse server?

I have a local parse server where the mobile app is connected, then the local parse server will sync to the cloud parse server.

My situation is I have local parse server with local mongodb.
The local parse server every night or when internet is available it will sync to the cloud parse server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You don't sync Parse servers**. You just setup a database (mongodb) where the server should read or write the data.  The database can be hosted in local or cloud mongodb (like mlab.com, for instance). 
The server can be local or cloud.
If I understand well your question, you just have to setup your local mongodb uri in both parse servers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to sync Parse-servers, your local parse-server is pointing to local database and your remote parse server is pointing to remote database. I don't think there is possibility of sync.

By default objectId is never changed by  open parse-server, unless you are running some kind of jobs on your database.